# How do I let the user jump to the next fitting item after pressing a key in an WPF Data grid?

Tags: wpf, datagrid

This is the WPF-Datagrid I use:

```
<DataGrid Grid.Row="1" x:Name="products" CanUserAddRows="true" MouseDoubleClick="products_MouseDoubleClick" InitializingNewItem="products_InitializingNewItem" IsReadOnly="True"/>
```

The products-Dataset has a Property called "Nickname" and is sorted by this property. When the user presses a letter (for example "m") I want my datagrid to select the next Row with a nickname starting with "m".

In short: I want my dataGrid show the standard behavior like most datagrids in Windows (e.g. explorer).

This code:

```
private void products_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    foreach (ProductDatasource item in products.Items)
    {
        if (item.Nickname.StartsWith(e.Key.ToString()))
        {
            Debug.Print("Found it, but how to set the selection?");
        }
    } 
}
```

will find the first Item which starts with the letter. But how can I select this item?

And as pretty every Grid in windows shows the same behavior (even in a more complicated way like starting the search from the current position; if you press 2 keys shortly after another like "mi" it searches for the next item starting with "mi") I wonder if the DataGrid has built in behavior I can use to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the `SelectedItem` property of the `DataGrid`:

```
private void products_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    foreach (ProductDatasource item in products.Items)
    {
        if (item.Nickname.StartsWith(e.Key.ToString()))
        {
            products.SelectedItem = item;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. It worked. I added a products.ScrollIntoView(item); after the selection so the item is visible too. But this is just the absolute basic functionality how datagrids usually work. Is there no default behavior which does exactly this which I just have to enable? I really dont want to reinvent the wheel that hundreds of datagrid users already implemented...